# Display files on HTML page as it is

Tags: python, html, web.py

I am using webpy framework for my project. I want to pass a file from my webpy program and display it on html page as it is(files may be any text files/program files). I passed a text file using following function from my webpy program.

```
class display_files:
    def GET(self):
        wp=web.input()
        file_name=wp.name
        repo_name=wp.repo
        repo_path=os.path.join('repos',repo_name)
        file_path=os.path.join(repo_path,file_name)
        fp=open(file_path,'rU')             #reading file from file path
        text=fp.read()                      #no problem found till this line.
        fp.close()            
        return render.file_display(text) #calling file_display.html
```

When I tried to display the file (here it is 'text') from 'file_display.html', it displays continuously without recognising   newline.Here is my html file.

```
$def with(content)
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/string;charset=utf-8" >
    <title>File content</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="file_content" id="file_content" methode="GET">
        <p> $content</p>
    </form>
</body>
<html>
```

How can I display file as it is in html page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML treats amount of whitespace characters as a single whitespace. If the file that you are displaying contains this text:

```
line one
  line two with indent
```

the rendered `file_display.html` will contain this HTML:

```
<p> line one
  line two with indent</p>
```

Still, the newline and two spaces will be treated as a single space, and in browser it will look like this:

```
line one line two with indent
```

[The `pre` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/text.html#edef-PRE) tells the browser that the text inside it is preformatted, so newlines and spaces should be kept. Thus, your template should look like:

```
<form name="file_content" id="file_content" methode="GET">
    <pre>$content</pre>
</form>
```

As for Joseph's advice, web.py templating system will handle escaping for you. If your file contains characters like `<` or `>`, they will be replaced with `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

Comment: Thank you very much Helgi. Your answer is absolutely right.  Thanks to Joseph too for his reply.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you may need to globally replace any < or > with &lt; or &gt; respectively:

http://jsfiddle.net/BaULp/

Comment: I'm pretty sure `file_display.html` is a web.py template file, not the file Umni is going to show. No need to escape the template.

Comment: @Helgi ah. I don't know about web.py. I was just trying to figure out a way to show HTML between `pre` tags as I thought that was the question. :P  Thanks for the info!